# PyQt5 изменять размер виджета вместе с изменением размера окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout, qwebengineview

Если кратко, то нужно при изменении размера окна изменять размер виджета `QWebEngineView`.

Код на данный момент:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1280, 720) #Здесь размер окна (изначальный)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.web = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget) #Здесь тот самый виджет
        self.web.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 1271, 671))
        self.web.setObjectName("web")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        

        self.web.load(QUrl("https://google.com"))
        self.web.show()

        self.add_funcs()

    def resizeEvent(self, event): #Здесь попытки сделать функцию отслеживания изменения размера главного окна
        print("Something")
        width = self.MainWindow.frameGeometry().width()
        height = self.MainWindow.frameGeometry().height()
        self.web.setGeometry(0, 40, width-9, height-49)
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick проверьте

Comment: kingley, я же вам написал, что пример должен быть ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫМ, т.е. я хочу скопировать ваш пример и запустить его и увидеть что у вас уже написано. Но увы ваш пример НЕ ЗАПУСКАЕТСЯ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

[**Layout Management**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)
Система компоновки Qt предоставляет простой и мощный способ
автоматического размещения дочерних виджетов внутри виджета.
...

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1280, 720)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
# +++        
#       self.url_area = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
# ------------------------------> v^v^v^v^v
        self.url_area = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)              # +++
        
        self.url_area.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 0, 791, 41))
        self.url_area.setObjectName("url_area")
        
        self.refresh_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.refresh_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 0, 41, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.refresh_btn.setFont(font)
        self.refresh_btn.setObjectName("refresh_btn")
        
        self.back_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.back_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 41, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.back_btn.setFont(font)
        self.back_btn.setObjectName("back_btn")
        
        self.forward_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.forward_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 0, 41, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.forward_btn.setFont(font)
        self.forward_btn.setObjectName("forward_btn")
        
        self.home_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.home_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 0, 41, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.home_btn.setFont(font)
        self.home_btn.setObjectName("home_btn")
        
        self.web = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)
        self.web.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 40, 1271, 671))
        self.web.setObjectName("web")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        pass


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.back_btn.setFixedSize(41, 41)
        self.forward_btn.setFixedSize(41, 41)
        self.refresh_btn.setFixedSize(41, 41)
        self.home_btn.setFixedSize(41, 41)
        self.url_area.setMinimumHeight(41)
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.back_btn, 0, 0, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.forward_btn, 0, 1, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.refresh_btn, 0, 2, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.home_btn, 0, 3, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.url_area, 0, 4)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.web, 1, 0, 1, 5)
   
        self.web.load(QUrl("https://google.com"))
   
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @kingley пожалуйста.